# JavaFX code cannot connect to jersey web service

Tags: java, web-services, security, jersey, javafx

I'm building a JavaFX GUI which I want to run in a browser. The GUI connects to a Jersey Webservice, and runs fine if I run the JavaFX code as standalone, however, if I run in a browser I get the exception below. I have self-signed my jar file and the problem is still there: 


`Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.BufferSize" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.FXAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.getBufferSize(ReaderWriter.java:91)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.(ReaderWriter.java:87)`

Thanks in advance.